# Pipe users to change their passwords

Tags: command-line, bash, passwd

I am trying to make a bash command change all user's passwords to x.

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Can I pipe the users that are returned to `passwd`? I mean is that gonna require some kind of loop? If that is the case please do an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

`passwd` does not read passwords non-interactively e.g. via STDIN generated by pipe, as an alternative you can use `chpasswd` which reads password via STDIN but has a security issue.

The problem is `chpasswd` expects passwords to be given in clear text, following the format:

```
username:password
```

To make us somewhat less explicit we can save the passwords sequentially in separate lines in a file corresponding to the output given by the `awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd` command. Remember you need to maintain the sequence of the output of the command while saving passwords in the file.

Then we can use `paste` to generate the format `chpasswd` wants on its STDIN.

For example:

```
paste -d: <(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd)\
          /password/file | sudo chpasswd
```

Here `/password/file` contains the relevant passwords.

As a safety measure, we can remove the `/password/file` file afterwards.

Comment: `passwd does not read passwords via STDIN`  ? So what is keyboard then if not STDIN ?

Comment: @Serg Oops..I meant pipe..

Comment: No, you meant stdin. @Serg It just happens that passwd only reads from stdin if it is connected to a TTY.

Comment: @muru well, that's not "just happens" , it's by design, but for some users it well may be confusing

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `usermod -p PASSWD USERNAME` and while loop. Problem is that PASSWD cannot be in plain text, it has to be encrypted password. For that purpose you can use `mkpasswd`. That way "newPassString" is encrypted , and remains the same for all users.   Here's example of what can be done in just one line of code.

```
$ cat userlist |  while read USERNAME; do echo "$USERNAME";sudo usermod -p "$(mkpasswd "newPassString")" "$USERNAME"  ;done
tester
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
testuser
[sudo] password for xieerqi:
```

Notice that i have to enter `sudo` for each `sudo` call - that's my personal setting. In regular, unaltered `/etc/sudoers` file, the timeout is 15 minutes by default, so you'd need to enter it only once.

A better approach is to put the code into a script, and call with parameters  $1 as filename and $2 as new password string   :

```
 xieerqi:$ cat passScript.sh                                                                                        
#!/bin/bash
while read USERNAME; do
   echo "$USERNAME";
   usermod -p "$(mkpasswd "$2")" "$USERNAME"  
done < "$1"

xieerqi:$ chmod +x passScript.sh                                                                                   

xieerqi:$ sudo ./passScript.sh  userlist myNewPass                                                                 
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
tester
testuser

xieerqi:$ su testuser
Password: 
testuser@eagle:/home/xieerqi$
```

Comment: Why specify a salt to `mkpasswd`? It can generate salts (and does, if you don't specify one).

Comment: @muru so that the user can go back and check it. But if 100% unnecessary, i can remove it

Comment: Of course it is unnecessary! Adding a constant salt to everything negates the whole point of a salt.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, have a read through http://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983/54387 and http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/54387 to see why using the same salt for all passwords defeats the purpose of a salt. In this specific case, even though all the passwords are being set to `x`, a future attacker who does not know of this cannot take advantage of it - each hash will look different, and will have to be cracked individually. With the same salt, the hashes will all be the same - crack one, crack all.